# JavaMail MIME attachment link by cid

Tags: ios, jakarta-mail, html-email, email-attachments

**Background**

I have banged my head against this for a while and not made much progress. I am generating MPEG_4 / AAC files in Android and sending them by email as .mp3 files. I know they aren't actually .mp3 files, but that allows Hotmail and Gmail to play them in Preview. They don't work on iPhone though, unless they are sent as .m4a files instead which breaks the Outlook / Gmail Preview.

So I have thought of a different approach which is to attach as a .mp3 file but have an HTML link in the email body which allows the attached file to be downloaded and specifies a .m4a file name. Gmail / Outlook users can click the attachment directly whereas iPhone users can use the HTML link.

**Issue**

I can send an email using JavaMail with HTML in it including a link which should be pointing at the attached file to allow download of that file by the link. Clicking on the link in Gmail (Chrome on PC) gives a 404 page and iPhone just ignores my clicking on the link.

Below is the code in which I generate a multipart message and assign a CID to the attachment which I then try to access using the link in the html part. It feels like I am close, but maybe that is an illusion. I'd be massively grateful if someone could help me fix it or save me the pain if it isn't possible.

```
private int send_email_temp(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtp_host_setting);
    //props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtp_port_setting);

    session = Session.getInstance(props);

    ActuallySendAsync_temp asy = new ActuallySendAsync_temp(true);
    asy.execute();

    return 0;
}


class ActuallySendAsync_temp extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    public ActuallySendAsync_temp(boolean boo) {
        // something to do before sending email
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(recipient_email_address));
            message.setSubject(email_subject);

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String file = mFileName;
            /**/
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            /* /
            File ff = new File(file);
            try {
                messageBodyPart.attachFile(ff);
            } catch(IOException eio) {
                Log.e("Message Error", "Old Macdonald");
            }
            /* /
            messageBodyPart = new PreencodedMimeBodyPart("base64");
            byte[] file_bytes = null;
            File ff = new File(file);
            try {
                int length = (int) ff.length();
                BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(ff));
                file_bytes = new byte[length];
                reader.read(file_bytes, 0, length);
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException eio) {
                Log.e("Message Error", "Old Macdonald");
            }
            messageBodyPart.setText(Base64.encodeToString(file_bytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
            /**/
            messageBodyPart.setFileName( DEFAULT_AUDIO_FILENAME );//"AudioClip.mp3");
            //messageBodyPart.setContentID("<audio_clip>");
            String content_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            messageBodyPart.setContentID("<" + content_id + ">");
            messageBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);//INLINE);
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mp4");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyText = new MimeBodyPart();
            //final String MY_HTML_MESSAGE = "<h1>My HTML</h1><a download=\"AudioClip.m4a\" href=\"cid:audio_clip\">iPhone Download</a>";
            final String MY_HTML_MESSAGE = "<h1>My HTML</h1><a download=\"AudioClip.m4a\" href=\"cid:" + content_id + "\">iPhone Download</a>";
            messageBodyText.setContent( MY_HTML_MESSAGE, "text/html");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyText);
            message.setContent(multipart);

            Print_Message_To_Console(message);

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(smtp_host_setting, username, password);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        // something to do after sending email
    }
}

int Print_Message_To_Console(Message msg) {
    int ret_val = 0;
    int line_num = 0;

    InputStream in = null;
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
    BufferedReader buff_reader = null;
    try {
        in = msg.getInputStream();
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
        buff_reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String temp = "";
        while ((temp = buff_reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("Message Line " + Integer.toString(line_num++), temp);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("Message Lines", "------------ OOPS! ------------");
        ret_val = 1;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (buff_reader != null) buff_reader.close();
            if (inputStreamReader != null) inputStreamReader.close();
            if (in != null) in.close();
        } catch(Exception e2) {
            Log.d("Message Lines", "----------- OOPS! 2 -----------");
            ret_val = 2;
        }
    }

    return ret_val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create a multipart/related](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#sendmpr) and set the main text part as the first body part.

Comment: I have changed to Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related"); and moved the multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); to after multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyText); but still get the 404 on Gmail. The attachment is visible in Gmail but no longer visible in Mail on iPhone.

Comment: 404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /zaFuceKimZiT1vmMERY.......=s0-l75-ft-l75-ft was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: If I set the String file to an image file and the String MY_HTML_MESSAGE = "<h1>My HTML</h1><img src=\"cid:" + content_id + "\">", comment out the messageBodyPart.setFileName line and the messageBodyPart.setHeader line the image does appear in  the resulting email

Comment: Sorry Bill. No it doesn't fix what I need. It seems to work for images, but not for download links. Do you think that means it's a limitation of the email client software?

Comment: Probably.  You're really pushing the limits of what most mailers can do.